# Asp.Net Core Querystring Parameters not being decoded

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a legacy application calling a ASP.NET Core API passing addresses as a querystring parameter. Sometimes these addresses contain French (fr-CA) characters. The application URL encodes the address and we end up with something like:

"123 DE L'%C9CUME" (instead of "123 DE L'ÉCUME")

The problem is inside the controller function I still see it as "123 DE L'%C9CUME" as it's not being decoded.

If I pass the string through `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode`, I end up with "123 DE L'�CUME".

I'm quite new to .NET Core so wondering if I'm missing a step like adding supported languages to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the string was not being properly url encoded on the legacy application side. Out of the control of the API.

Once legacy application was adjusted to properly encode, things worked as expected.